Owl carousel show double image in items:1 responsive view settings
owl carousel not working on mobile view or responsive settings items:1
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme pt-16 xxl:pt-20 h-full" id="carousel8">
   <div class="group flex justify-around items-center centerwrap">
     <div class="centerwidth">
        <Img class="object-cover w-full" src="images/car/carslide1.png"></Img>
     </div>
     /* other content stuff */         
   </div>
   <div class="group flex justify-around items-center centerwrap">
     <div class="centerwidth">
        <Img class="object-cover w-full" src="images/car/carslide1.png"></Img>
     </div>
     /* other content stuff */         
   </div>
   <div class="group flex justify-around items-center centerwrap">
     <div class="centerwidth">
        <Img class="object-cover w-full" src="images/car/carslide1.png"></Img>
     </div>
     /* other content stuff */         
   </div>
</div>

owl-item.center .centerwrap given height 50rem , owl-item .centerwidth image container width given 50% owl-item.center .centerwidth given 100% width .. everythings fine but when , items:1 configuration gives in mobile view it show double image like provided image example..
example image
trying to understand or solve problems

thanks , i'm trying to both repair and use it in new project, i was completely unaware about it's depreciation. do you have any suggesstion which alternative to use against owl carousel
